# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int). How o rectify this type of error in python?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, valueerror

My training data size and testing data size is ((80000, 77, 1), (8000, 77, 1))
[training and testing data shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9CoQ.png)
fit the data into CNN model during implementation am getting value error

tried to fit my data to CNN model during the training process am getting value error as
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

I tried using these commands still error occurs as:
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10.152.152.11-50.23.134.226-41711-80-6'

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Can you provide a reproducible snippet of the source code?

Comment: Please help us to know what this data looks like or You need to do preprocessing of the dataset before model training.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way you have tried to convert to numpy array :

> ```
> x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32) 
>
> y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
> ```

You can as well use this function :

```
X_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype = tf.float32)
```

However the problem is lying not in the function, but in the data :

there is a string value which is preventing the conversion to numpy array :

'10.152.152.11-50.23.134.226-41711-80-6'

you can find the exact location of the string by using :

```
df.loc[df.column_name=='10.152.152.11-50.23.134.226-41711-80-6']
```

convert this value to a suitable value which you want it to be .

Or

Replace this value with the mean/median of the column and then use `model.fit()` as you have used earlier.

This will remove the error while converting to Tensor/Numpy.